# How do I fix my conditional statement for marks input in Python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have recently started learning python and we were asked to work on conditional statements.

I have tried to use if,elif and else functions. I put the code on python IDLE and then run it.

```
a=int(input("Enter the Math number"))
b=int(input("Enter the Phy number"))
c=int(input("Enter the Chem number"))


Total=a+b+c
print=['Total']
Average=Total/3

print=['Average']

if(Average>=90):
print=('Excellent')
elif(Average>=80 and Average>=90):
print=('Very Good')
elif(Average>=70 and Average>=80):
print=('Good')
elif(Average>=60 and Average>=70):
print=('Ok')
else:print('sorry try again')
```

When I try to run the code it only shows the input stages. It wont print the Total, Average, if,elif and else functions. Please help me find the mistake in my code. Thank you:)

Comment: Please format your code properly - specifically, by indenting it. Not only does this make the code much easier to read (making it easier to help you) but in python, it matters! Your current example will not run due to syntax errors.

Comment: Think about your conditions… *if average is over 90… __else__ if average is over 80 and over 90…* — Doesn’t make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the print method incorrectly.

You were assigning the values to a list called print not printing them!

The code below works. I also changed the second operand after the 'AND' operator, though this operation is redundant.

```
a=int(input("Enter the Math number: "))

b=int(input("Enter the Phy number: ")) 

c=int(input("Enter the Chem number: ")) 

Total=a+b+c 
print('Total = ', Total)
Average=Total/3 
print('Average = ', Average)

if(Average>=90): 

    print('Excellent') 

elif(Average>=80 and Average<90):        

    print('Very Good')

elif(Average>=70 and Average<80):

     print('Good') 

elif(Average>=60 and Average<70):

     print('Ok')

else:

    print('sorry try again')
```

Comment: This prints “Good” for a score of 80, and will never print “Very Good”...

Comment: It is now fixed, didnt see the logic errors in 'if' block

Comment: The `and ...` comparison is still superfluous though and should be omitted entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the `print` function to a list here:

```
print=['Average']
```

Change it to

```
print(Average)
```

Not related to the issue you are having, but your conditions don't make much sense, for example:

```
elif(Average>=80 and Average>=90):
```

which should probably be

```
elif(Average>=80 and Average<=90):
```

or

```
elif 90 >= Average >= 80:
```

Comment: You don’t need a `<=` test of the previous value in an `elif`. `if ... >= 90: ... elif ... >= 80: ...` is already sufficient.

Answer (score -2):

indentation is wrong . if statement should be well indented.

```
a=int(input("Enter the Math number"))
b=int(input("Enter the Phy number"))
c=int(input("Enter the Chem number"))


Total=a+b+c
print=(Total)
Average=Total/3

print=(Average)

if(Average>=90):
    print=('Excellent')
elif(Average>=80 and Average>=90):
    print=('Very Good')
elif(Average>=70 and Average>=80):
    print=('Good')
elif(Average>=60 and Average>=70):
    print=('Ok')
else:
    print('sorry try again')
```

when you want to print a variable don't use ' ', it become string instead of variable name

print is a function print() not an array so use it as a function.

Comment: 1) "_when you want to print a variable don't use ' '_" What about f-strings? 2) "_array->print[]_" This may seem confusing to readers. Currently, there's no such thing in Python. 3) Optimally, the code shown should incorporate all the necessary changes to make it work. Although indentation is fixed, the print statements are still awry and there is a logic error in the conditionals.